# Google My Maps - how to remove labels, advertising etc?

Tags: google-maps, google-my-maps

Google My Maps functionality allows you to create your own maps to share.  Unfortunately it has a lot of noisy labels which makes the maps hard to read.  https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/

Is there a way to turn the labels off before you send the link?  Or even afterwards?

Here is my map and it seems the burger option isn't available

https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1cEMk-vbmQ3b9njjx89prZ3prV0nqqeRN&ll=50.83123010718299%2C-0.1421468118693383&z=16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the base map, "Simple Atlas" view displays nicely without other default labels.

Answer (score -3):

It is a problem but I think that there is also an option here:

[https://www.viamichelin.com/web/Maps]

It is a Michelin Map service and you are able to select the style of map from 5 options. There is a drop down list to the right of the map image. In my case I wanted zero labels on the base map but didn't quite make that, it did however give me great start and all I had to do was manually remove the very few place names, half a dozen or so.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).